# AKS : Kubernetes coreDNS fails to resolve headless services

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, azure-aks, coredns

We have multiple headless service running in our Azure's AKS VMAS cluster. Sometimes (randomly), we have observed that the coredns fails to resolve the headless services with the following error logs:

E0909 09:31:22.241120       1 runtime.go:73] Observed a panic: "invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference" (runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference)

Please note that, while facing the above mentioned issues, the non-headless service(services which have cluster IPs), gets resolved properly without any hassle.

For resolving the issue in the dev/svt environment, we terminate the coredns pod in kube-system namespace, and everything starts working fine again, for brief period of time - 1/2 days.

This deletion operation cannot be performed in the customer deployment scenario.

We raised a ticket with the AKS team, but since coredns is a third-party project, it doesn't come under Azure's support domain.

Has anyone faced this issue with coredns?
What is the permanent solution for this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will help someone https://github.com/coredns/coredns/issues/4022
This is a known defect in CoreDNS you need to upgrade CoreDNS inside AKS to use a newer version with the fix applied 1.7.0

Comment: it will be great if you would have used it as the comment instead of an answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have the required reputation to do it

Comment: They have tracked a defect in AKS
https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/2218